# Correct way to structure a Crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am starting to write a crate for a specific API.  I have read the Modules section of The Rust Reference but I'm unclear if the following 2 file structures are equivalent, and is there a preferable/idiomatic approach?

```
some-crate/
|- src/
|   |- bits.rs
|   |- bobs.rs
|   |- lib.rs
|- foo/
|   |- mod.rs
|- bar/
|   |- mod.rs
```

or

```
some-crate/
|- src/
|   |- bits.rs
|   |- bobs.rs
|   |- lib.rs
|   |- foo.rs
|   |- bar.rs
```

I would like to access my sub-level functions with the following notation `some-crate::foo::do_this();`

The sub-level modules would require access to common items in `bits.rs` and `bobs.rs`.

There will be 4 sub-level modules so not a large file structure to manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo/` and `bar/` should be inside of `src/`. The two options are:

```
some-crate/             some-crate/
|- src/                 |- src/
|   |- bar/             |   |- bar.rs
|   |   |- mod.rs       |   |- bits.rs
|   |- foo/             |   |- bobs.rs
|   |   |- mod.rs       |   |- foo.rs
|   |- bits.rs          |   |- lib.rs
|   |- bobs.rs          |- Cargo.toml
|   |- lib.rs           
|- Cargo.toml
```

Which to use is a matter of taste.

Personally, I use `mod.rs` once a module gets sub-modules because otherwise `foo.rs` and `foo/` end up visually separated since file viewers usually sort directories before files (see example on right):

```
some-crate/             some-crate/
|- src/                 |- src/
|   |- bar/             |   |- bar/
|   |   |- mod.rs       |   |    |- baz.rs
|   |   |- baz.rs       |   |- foo/
|   |- foo/             |   |    |- quux.rs
|   |   |- mod.rs       |   |- bar.rs
|   |   |- quux.rs      |   |- bits.rs
|   |- bits.rs          |   |- bobs.rs
|   |- bobs.rs          |   |- foo.rs
|   |- lib.rs           |   |- lib.rs
|- Cargo.toml           |- Cargo.toml
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first example, `foo` and `bar` are not part of your crate at all, since they aren't in the `src` directory. You may have meant to write it this way:

```
some-crate/
|- src/
|   |- bits.rs
|   |- bobs.rs
|   |- lib.rs
|   |- foo/
|       |- mod.rs
|   |- bar/
|       |- mod.rs
```

This example and your second example are both equivalent, and I would argue the second way is better if you have small, related modules, and this way would be better if there was more of a logical distinction between them (my brain likes visual separation). If `foo` and `bar` eventually had sub-modules themselves, however, then using nested directories would be much preferable to nested `mod` blocks within a single file.

In your `lib.rs`, you can also use `pub use` and `pub mod` to change how your modules are accessed by others (to a certain extent).